# HTML Video doesn't work unless cache is disabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, hapi.js

I'm using api to just serve static video files to a `<video>` tag. However, unless I run chrome with caching disabled it doesn't load the videos.

What could cause this?

Comment: Um, what is this *tag*?

Comment: Not quite following?

Comment: try opening Developer Tools and seeing what's happening in terms of network requests

Comment: "static video files to a tag" what is a tag?

Comment: video tag. I forgot to escape the <>.

Comment: @codebox: I get a 206 Partial Content with just a few kb of data and then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779) bugReport it could be related with your bug. They solve it with adding some fake parameter to the video `src` attribute

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
player[0].setAttribute('src','video.webm?i='+timestamp);
```